# PHP controlled by SMS

Tags: php, sms, voice

I am looking to create a script that is run based on receiving and the content of a text. So I text a phone number (Google Voice number). And the script reads it and executes based on the content. Is the possible to do?

Comment: best way is to sign up to an sms provider and the use their api.

Answer (score 1):

We use an SMS provider called textmagic, but many will be the same, in that they offer an API to use, and/or email notifications. You can set up your account to email you or call an web page with customer parameters when a text message is received (and indeed the other way round to text back).

One thing we used to do was hook up a mobile to a com-port and use our own sim, but this is very hacky and ought to be used as a last resort.